# Tkinter method on returning value from TopLevel object to root object

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a Tkinter app that calls `TopLevel` objects from another file (for menu bar options).

In my `main.py`, I have this code:

```
...
def create():
    funct.createNew()
...

menubar = tk.Menu(window)
#file menu
file = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
file.add_command(label='Create new', command=create)
...
```

And the function being called from `functions.py` file (I removed the window attributes for simplicity):

```
def linkToDB():
    global create

    #call the function to create virtual file
    file = sql.generateDB()
    #destroy the createNew window
    create.destroy()

    #debugging purposes
    print("Virtual file:", file)

def createNew():
    #make this global to destroy this window later
    global create

    create = tk.Toplevel()
    ...
    #option 1
    container1 = tk.Frame(create)
    ...
    #generate virtual SQLite file
    btn1 = tk.Button(container1, text="Create", command= lambda: linkToDB())
```

The above code displays a `TopLevel` window that will be called by <kbd>Create</kbd> button in `main.py`, which in turn calls a function from `sql.py` (by that button within `TopLevel` window) to create temporary SQlite file:

```
import sqlite3 as sq

#create a virtual sqlite file
def generateDB():
    temp = sq.connect(':memory:')
    temp.execute...
    return temp
```

My problem is how to return the value of **`temp`** from `generateDB()` to `main.py` (specifically after destroying the `TopLevel` window)? I am confused on how to pass this value across the .py files. And whether my approach is viable or not (also looking for suggestions).

*P.S. I intentionally destroyed the `TopLevel` window in `linkToDB()` since it is guaranteed that my temporary SQlite file will be generated.*

Comment: See [How do I share global variables across modules?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify `funct.createNew()` to return the *virtual file* to `main.py`. However you need to make the toplevel window a modal window in order to return the virtual file after the toplevel window is destroyed.

Below is the modified `functions.py`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import sql

# pass the toplevel window as an argument instead of using global variable
def linkToDB(create):
    # use an attribute of the toplevel window to store the "virtual db file"
    create.file = sql.generateDB()
    create.destroy()
    print('Virtual file:', create.file)

def createNew():
    create = tk.Toplevel()
    ...
    container1 = tk.Frame(create)
    ...
    btn1 = tk.Button(container1, text='Create', command=lambda: linkToDB(create))
    ...
    # wait for window destroy (works like a modal dialog)
    create.wait_window(create)
    # return the "virtual db file"
    return create.file
```

Then you can get the virtual db file in `main.py`:

```py
def create():
    # if you want the "virtual db file" be accessed by other function
    # declare it as global variable
    #global db_file
    db_file = funct.createNew()
    print(db_file)
    ...

...
```

Comment: I never thought about using the TopLevel window as an argument. For the create.wait_window() it will run the return statement below?

Comment: As said in the comment in my code, `create.wait_window(create)` will wait for the `create` window to be destroyed.  After `create` window is destroyed, `return create.file` will be executed.